# Variable Table Inner components width not working html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build this excel table with html and css. The problem i kept facing is the when i try to add different number of columns for different rows, It surpasses the border limit and extends by itself. My intent is to replicate the contents of the picture.[image]

```css
table
   {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #151515;
   }
   th, td
   {
    border: 1px solid #151515;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
   }
   th
   {
    font-weight: bold;
   }
   tfoot tr:nth-child(2)
   {
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 100px;
   }
   .colored td
   {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
   }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" class="title">PURCHASE DETAILS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="colored">
      <th rowspan="2">BUDGET CODE:</th>
      <td>Account Code</td>
      <td>Cost Center</td>
      <td>Project Code</td>
      <td>DEA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5458</td>
      <td>22222</td>
      <td>3658954</td>
      <td>95874</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>PO Number:</th>
      <td>PO/SC/2010/33</td>
      <th>Supplier:</th>
      <td>STORM TECH</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>SOF:</th>
      <td>00254584</td>
      <th>Value (Purchase Price USD):</th>
      <td><b>1,084.89</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Plan After Award Ends:</th>
      <td colspan="2">Carry Over</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

If anybody can assist please.

Comment: I don't see what's broken, could you elaborate?

Comment: On the budget code row, It extends outside the table border as you can see the difference between the picture and the table i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure table layout is the best choice here, but it can be done. Just create more cells per row and span the cells you need over 2 or 3 "cells"

```css
table
   {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #151515;
   }
   th, td
   {
    border: 1px solid #151515;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
   }
   th
   {
    font-weight: bold;
   }
   tfoot tr:nth-child(2)
   {
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 100px;
   }
   .colored td
   {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
   }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="8" class="title">PURCHASE DETAILS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="colored">
      <th rowspan="2">BUDGET CODE:</th>
      <td colspan="2">Account Code</td>
      <td colspan="2">Cost Center</td>
      <td colspan="2">Project Code</td>
      <td>DEA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">5458</td>
      <td colspan="2">22222</td>
      <td colspan="2">3658954</td>
      <td>95874</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>PO Number:</th>
      <td colspan="3">PO/SC/2010/33</td>
      <th colspan="2">Supplier:</th>
      <td colspan="2">STORM TECH</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>SOF:</th>
      <td colspan="3">00254584</td>
      <th colspan="2">Value (Purchase Price USD):</th>
      <td colspan="2"><b>1,084.89</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Plan After Award Ends:</th>
      <td colspan="6">Carry Over</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```